# How to access to Webview declared in onCreate from outside?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview

I'm trying to develop some simple app based on WebView, and make possible to exchange data between android app and remote page.

Problem description:

loadUrl works within onCreate, but not working from outside of onCreate. Please see code below and explain what I doing wrong, why it's not working within WebAppInterface class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public WebView view1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "htxx://mydomain.com/";
        final WebView view1 =(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view1.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android"); //exchange between web-js and webview
        WebSettings webSettings = view1.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view1.loadUrl(url);
        view1.setWebViewClient(new com.example.project.MyAppWebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view1, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        view1.setInitialScale(100);

        ///// ---> That's works:
        view1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                view1.loadUrl("javascript:somescript('Page is loaded')");
            }
        });

        ///// ---> That's works too:
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                String device_id = tm.getDeviceId();
                view1.loadUrl("javascript:somescript('"+device_id+"')");
            }
        });
    }

    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            //show toast from web-app (js to android)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void printFromWeb() {
            //show toast from web-app (js to android)

            ///// ---> That's NOT working :(
            view1.loadUrl("javascript:somescript('Checking loadurl from outside of onCreate')");
        }
    }
}
```

Interesting, that not any errors occurs in Android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `public WebView view1;` as a field and completely different final `view1` inside `onCreate()`, so it's actually null in your `public void printFromWeb()` method.

---

Here is the safe route to go:

To access WebView "from outside", add a private field of WebView class:

```
private WebView webView;
```

In your `onCreate()` method, instantiate it:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Add a getter method to access the instance:

```
public WebView getWebView() {
    return webView;
}
```

**And remember to only touch it only on UI thread.**

---

Update: how to safely access views from not-ui thread:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        view1.loadUrl(...)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's work! But i don't understand your last recommendation, and I getting same (as you described) message in logcat: _Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads._

Comment: @deeplay, the problem is that calling method on View descendant from outside UI thread breaks the rule _"do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread"_. [http://nickthecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/updating-ui-from-another-thread-in-android](Here) is an article which should make it clearer. Meanwhile, i'll update my post with relevant snippet

Comment: _[OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND.](https://nickthecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/updating-ui-from-another-thread-in-androi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bd)_

Comment: dang! https://nickthecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/updating-ui-from-another-thread-in-android/

Comment: Interesting. It's works now without any Warnings, perfect. Thank you very much, xAF. That's what i call clear answer :)